# Django/Celery - Object matching query does not exist only when using delay

Tags: django, celery, django-celery, celery-task

I am working with Django and Celery to asynchronously send_mass_mail. When I call the view function that calls the task, I get the following error:

[2020-09-08 17:47:49,148: ERROR/ForkPoolWorker-8] Task main_app.tasks.send_notice[244944f6-604c-47a0-901a-4c510563d76e] raised unexpected: DoesNotExist('Notice matching query does not exist.')

This only happens when I am using delay. If I call send_notice_task(notice_id) instead of send_notice_task.delay(notice_id) it can find the notice, but with delay it keeps throwing that error. Any ideas?

/views.py

```
def notice_approve(request, notice_id):
    notice = Notice.objects.get(id=notice_id)
    notice.approve()
    # send_notice_task(notice_id)
    send_notice_task.delay(notice_id)
    return redirect('manage')
```

/tasks.py

```
def send_notice_task(notice_id):
    print(notice_id)
    notice = Notice.objects.get(id=notice_id)
    subscribers = Subscriber.objects.filter(approved=True)
    recipient_list = []
    for sub in subscribers:
        recipient_list.append(sub.email)
    datatuple = (f'{notice.subject} - Notice',
        html_message,
        'CONCERN Network <cnb@gmail.com>',
        recipient_list)
    send_mass_mail((datatuple,), fail_silently=False)
```

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue.

**Cause**: This occurred because the task runs before the query hits the database

**Solution**: So forcing the task to wait for 3 seconds before it runs solved it for me.

For example, by changing

```
send_notice_task.delay(notice_id)
```

to

```
send_notice_task.apply_async((order.id,), countdown=3)
```